# Add 'unlimited' options to wordpress plugin (store in array)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a plugin, where the user has the ability to 'customize' it, in the terms of adding an unlimited amount of new fields.

Instead of creating my own table in the database, I'd prefer to use the built in options (get_option, register_setting, etc). This would work perfectly for static inputs, but in my case, where the user can add as many new 'settings', I wonder what the solution is.

So when I'd like to retrieve the options, it would look something like this:

```
foreach(get_option('my_unlimited_options') as $name => $value) {

}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option_value in options table is of type longtext, in essence it can hold lots of characters so this will probably be enough ( but again depends on how many of these fields you are going to have), it would be serialized array inside of course

I have seen a quite number of themes using options field in this manner so it's probably ok